# How to mimic Form subform in livecode

Tags: livecode

I am a seasoned msaccess developer but new to livecode. I want to mimic the form/subform functionality of msaccess in a livecode application. I need some ideas on how to achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your own example. Make a new mainStack. Now make another mainstack, or a substack, resize it smaller than the first one, and overlay it.

You will need to manage which one is on top, and note that there are other stack modes that will do this for you, but in the meantime look up "the defaultStack" in the dictionary.

The two stacks give you all the power and flexibility you could possibly need, since each is on its own, and can contain any arbitrary functionality.

Craig

Answer (score 1):

This is easily and commonly done by overlaying a smaller stack onto the main stack. Each stack has its own set of controls and functionality. Each stack can directly communicate with the other.

Comment: Thanks Craig. Do you know where I can download so examples